# display title and url don't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I used this code:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame //2 errors on this line stating: expected ")" before "WebView" and expected ")" before "WebFrame"
{
    //Only report feedback from main frame.
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
        NSString *url = [[[[frame dataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
        [adressBar setStringValue:url];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didRecieveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame // Same 2 errors as the first line of code
{
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
        [[sender window] setTitle:title];
    }
}
```

but it doesn't set the title of the window or the complete url in the textfield... am I missing something?
Edit:
I have connnected everything.

Comment: Does the delegate methods get called?  Add a NSLog to see if it gets called.  I have the exact same code, and it works perfectly.  (Except I used `[frame provisionalDataSource]` instead)

Comment: I have the impression that OP can't even compile his code as he has compiler errors. @TheAmateurProgrammer just read the comments

Comment: @H2CO3 Oops I didn't expect there were comments after the method.  @user1649623 Perhaps you forgot a `}` or `)` in your previous method?

Comment: And i didn't forget any } or ) in my previous code.

Comment: @user1649623 You know how to do this, but you don't how to call NSLog...?  `NSLog (@"Test Message");`  But really, do try learn a bit of Cocoa before you do things like this...